# Finite groups inside an infinite group with the same homology

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gr.group-theory, finite-groups, group-cohomology

Suppose we have a triple of groups $G,H,K$ satisfying the following conditions:

1. $G$ and $H$ are finite groups and $K$ is an **infinite** group.
2. there exist two monomorphisms $G \rightarrow K \leftarrow H$ which induce an isomorphism in homology (with integral coefficients).

My question is the following: Is there a known triple $(K, G, H)$ satisfying the conditions (1.) and (2.) such that $G$ is not isomorphic to $H$? I am more interested in the case that $G$ is a perfect group, but any example (if there exists such) is welcome.

Edit: In the case where $K$ is finite, Culler's theorem says that $K, G, H$ are all isomorphic.

Comment: Does the proof of the case $K$ being finite has anything to do with some Eilenberg-Moore type spectral sequence? And how a comparison map $G\to H$ is constructed in the finite case? Is it constructed geometrically?

Comment: @user51223 Here is the reference   http://www.jstor.org/stable/2042568?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

Comment: @IliasA. I have undeleted this question which you have deleted last year. -- Please do not self-delete your useful questions!

Comment: Do you have an example of an infinite group K and a finite subgroup G such that the inclusion induces an isomorphism in cohomology?